# analyzing hacked website log : is thee any link between ./etc and ./tmp when uploading files ?

Tags: linux, security, ubuntu, centos, cpanel

so one of my friends got hacked and asked me for help 
this guy had a single shared host and uploaded like 20 website on that single host and one of them got hacked and now all of them are full of shells

so this happen today , so i asked for list of files that has been created or changed on the server since so i got the list something like below

the shell name is `accesson.php`  it first appears in

```
./etc/assets/images/accesson.php
```

and than in

```
./tmp/assets/images/accesson.php
```

log :

```
./etc
./etc/newsss.com
./etc/shsh.com
./etc/nck.com
./etc/pvf.com
./etc/pvf.com/@pwcache/info
./etc/lck.com
./etc/assets
./etc/assets/images
./etc/assets/images/accesson.php
./tmp
./tmp/assets
./tmp/assets/images
./tmp/assets/images/accesson.php
./mail
./mail/new
./mail/tmp
./mail/assets
./mail/assets/images
./mail/assets/images/accesson.php



./public_html
./public_html/images/2017/01/162210999.jpg.CROP_.cq5dam_web_1280_1280_jpeg-280x200.jpg
./public_html/wp-content/plugins
./public_html/.ftpquota
./public_html/backlinks/error_log
./public_html/app/images
./public_html/app/images/css_sprites.png
./public_html/app/index.php
./public_html/assets
./public_html/assets/images
./public_html/assets/images/accesson.php
./public_ftp
./public_ftp/assets
./public_ftp/assets/images
./public_ftp/assets/images/accesson.php

 ./irso.com
./irso.com/.ftpquota
./irso.com/wp-content/plugins
./irso.com/wp-content/themes
./irso.com/assets
./irso.com/assets/images
./irso.com/assets/images/accesson.php

./ncl2.com
./ncl2.com/assets
./ncl2.com/assets/images
./ncl2.com/assets/images/accesson.php
./cache
./cache/assets
./cache/assets/images
./cache/assets/images/accesson.php
./ssl
./ssl/assets
./ssl/assets/images
./ssl/assets/images/accesson.php


./efr.com
./efr.com/.ftpquota
./efr.com/assets
./efr.com/assets/images
./efr.com/assets/images/accesson.php
```

it seems `accesson.php` has been spread trough all directories interesting thing is its been created with its directory  `/assets/images/`  even in the tmp

so i thought since it first appeasers in ./tmp it must be uploaded trough some bug since all uploaded files first go to ./tmp but what about that ./etc ? its even before ./tmp .... so i thought maybe there is a link between the 2 ?

i appreciate any suggestion

Comment: This is a question for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) or a security professional.

Comment: If your server has been compromised, **quarantine it immediately**, back up everything, and build a new server from scratch. Restore only what you've carefully reviewed for any remnants of the hack. A single snippet of rogue PHP code could undo all of your hard work, so take your time.

Comment: @tadman thanx i know what to do to restore the server back safely ... but this question is not about that  ... im curious to know how this happen that's all

Comment: That's fine, but it's off-topic here as this is strictly for programming related questions, not security or server admin concerns.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This is now cross-posted with an answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/185281/analyzing-hacked-website-log-is-there-any-link-between-etc-and-tmp-when-up

Comment: That attack appears quite frequently on google, so probably you'll find recommendations on how to repair that.

Comment: From your question... normally there's no link from `/etc`  to `/tmp` in a normal system.  Having some of these can be a symptom of your system been hacked by someone.